# Why does jQuery.length == 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

For both current stable jQuery versions (1.11.0 & 2.1.0), I've noticed that `jQuery.length == 2` after jQuery is loaded.

Why is that ?

Both `jQuery[0]` and `jQuery[1]` are *undefined*.

I'm familliar with the jQuery array-like objects and console behavior regarding arrays/objects and objects with .length and .splice().

Just wondering about jQuery.length

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`jQuery` is a function, and the `length` property of a function equals the number of formal (declared) parameters to the function. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length):

> `length` is a property of a function object, and indicates how many arguments the function expects, i.e. the number of formal parameters. This number does not include the rest parameter. By contrast, `arguments.length` is local to a function and provides the number of arguments actually passed to the function.

Specifically, the `jQuery` function has this signature ([source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js)):

```
jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about that specificity.

Answer (score 10):

`jQuery` is a function.
The `length` property of a function returns the number of declared parameters.

Comment: And those parameters would be `( selector, context )`